# Getting an error of setUseState() is not a function when logging out

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on authentication using JWT, and for some reason if I logout from the home page when the url is '/', it logout just fine. But, when I do that from my profile where the path is '/:id' it shows this error:

```
TypeError: setRefreshCheckLogin is not a function

  14 | const user = userAuth()
  15 | const logout = () => {
  16 |     logoutApi();
> 17 |     setRefreshCheckLogin(true);
     | ^  18 | }
  19 | return (
  20 |     <div className="left-menu">
```

and once I refresh it does logout the user. So I am trying to figure out what is causing this issue of only logout when the url is '/'.

This is the logout function:

```
export default function LeftMenu(props) {
    const { setRefreshCheckLogin } = props
    const user = userAuth()
    const logout = () => {
        logoutApi();
        setRefreshCheckLogin(true);
    }
```

And I am passing that setRefreshCheckLogin as a prop from App.js where it is used in a useEffect,

```
  const [refreshCheckLogin, setRefreshCheckLogin] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setUser(isUserLoggedInApi());
    setRefreshCheckLogin(false);
    setLoadUser(true);
  }, [refreshCheckLogin])
```

This is how the logoutApi works:

```
export function logoutApi() {
    window.history.replaceState(null, "New Page Title", "/")
    localStorage.removeItem(TOKEN)
}
```

I tried the window.history.... line Thinking that it would cleanup the url and make it work but it didn't.

I am really out of ideas considering that this works if I logout from the '/' and technically it works on other paths but it shows that error, and then I have to refresh but it successfully gets rid off the token on localStorage.

Comment: You might not be passing this function as prop to leftMenu component

Comment: You need to show us where you are rendering `LeftMenu`. This would happen if the prop was not set properly.

Comment: When I console.log the props on the LeftMenu, it does show this, {setRefreshCheckLogin: ƒ}
setRefreshCheckLogin: ƒ ()
[[Prototype]]: Object
So it looks like it is passing it successfully

Comment: From App.js I do
 <Routing setRefreshCheckLogin={setRefreshCheckLogin}></Routing>
From Routing I do
<route.page setRefreshCheckLogin={setRefreshCheckLogin} />
From Home
        <BasicLayout className='home' setRefreshCheckLogin={setRefreshCheckLogin}>
From BasicLayout
 <LeftMenu setRefreshCheckLogin={setRefreshCheckLogin} />
And on LeftMenu
export default function LeftMenu(props) {
    const { setRefreshCheckLogin } = props
    console.log(props)
    const user = userAuth()
    const logout = () => {
        logoutApi();
        setRefreshCheckLogin(true);
    }